# Is there a way to display multiple authors on a post?

Tags: plugins, multi-author

I know I can add users and I already have the Co-Authors plug-in and it's letting met add two authors but only one is displayed on the page.

for reference, this is what displays at the top of my post, but I need another author to show up as well

[image]

Comment: You'll probably need to create a child theme to be able to show more than one. You might ask the Co-Authors developers if they have a recommended way to display the additional authors.

Comment: To be clear ... Are you using the original "Co-Authors" plugin, or the newer "Co-Authors Plus" plugin?  I ask because the newer plugin has a potential solution.

Comment: Thank you! I believe I'm using the original, but I will check.

Answer (score 0):

I am unfamiliar with the original. They may also have something similar to the new "Co-Authors Plus".  You would need to review that code for "apply_filters", "add_actions" or just global functions like those in "Co-Authors Plus".

Meanwhile, you might investigate migrating to the new version of "Co-Authors Plus".  They offer [a template tag, and pretty detailed instructions](https://wpvip.com/documentation/incorporate-co-authors-plus-template-tags-into-your-theme/) for how to use it.

Good luck!